# Table sorting for DD-MM-YYY hh:mm:ss not working

Tags: jquery, datetime, tablesorter

I have problem with sorting datetime format `DD-MM-YYY hh:mm:ss`. I tried several codes that I found online and none of them worked. Does someone knows where's the problem?

Here is code that I am using:

```
("#resultsTable").tablesorter({
    2: {
        sorter: "shortDate",
        dateFormat: "uk"
    }
});
```

Comment: You find answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091921/problem-with-sorting-dates-with-jquery-tablesorter

Comment: You want to sort using date only or date with time

Comment: @shri I want to sort by DateTime

Comment: did you try addParser..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849351/converting-a-datetime-string-to-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: You might want to check out my [fork of tableorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)... some of the options are slightly different, but the "shortDate" parser & ["dateFormat" option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#dateformat) will include "hh:mm:ss" automatically, so no need to add more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a `addParser` as code given below, This is simply convert time to numeric value and sort.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    id: 'date_column', // ID of the date column
    is: function(s) { 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { // convert datetime to timestamp
        var dateParts = s.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)/);
        date = new Date(dateParts[3], parseInt(dateParts[2], 10) - 1, dateParts[1], dateParts[4], dateParts[5]);
        return date.getTime();         
    }, 
    type: 'numeric' 
});
```

This is just a sample code for how to sort following date format

```
17-09-2013 10:08
date-month-year hour(24):minute
```

You need to convert it to the way you need, for more information refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849351/converting-a-datetime-string-to-timestamp-in-javascript).

Comment: thanks for help. With your suggestion I solve my problem. Regards.

Comment: Works like a charm!